# Retrieving subgraphs with property restrictions in Galaxybase graph database

Tags: graph-databases

During the retrieval of subgraphs using the n-step expansion API in Galaxybase, I have employed restrictions on vertexPropertySet and edgePropertySet to limit the returned data based on certain property values.

However, I observe that the results include data from vertex and edge types that do not match the specified restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in the subgraph retrieval API, VertexPropertySet and edgePropertySet impose restrictions on property values but not on property types. Therefore, it will display all data that meets the conditions, regardless of property type.